# Fluid row div stacking order - columnize when possible

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have the following stacking order for my footer

```
span2 |     span 8    | span2
```

If I halve the screen size, the stacking order is as follows:

```
|     span 8    |
|     span 2    |
|     span 2    |
```

But I want them to stack like this and I know there is enough space for 'span2's:

```
|     span 8    |
| span2 | span2 |
```

How can I achieve this? I tried appending `col-sm-6` to each `span2`, but with no luck (Boostrap [3.0.0-wip](http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-wip/js/bootstrap.min.js) and [2.2.1 no-icon](http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.1/css/bootstrap.no-icons.min.css))

Answer (score 0):

I'm playing with Bootstrap 3 since a couple of days. I think you need to do this:

```
<div class="col-6 col-lg-2"> 2 </div>
<div class="col-12 col-lg-8 "> 8 </div>
<div class="col-6 col-lg-2 "> 2 </div>
```

Does this work?

Comment: No. stacking order after the resize is the same, but stacking order before the resize is wrong. I now have each taking one row when they should be on the same one row.